# Convert datePicker UI to jalali in Odoo 8 (formerly openerp)

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, odoo, odoo-8

i'm using odoo 8 for our team and we need to implement Jalali(Persian) calendar for our customers, we've added one module that converts picked gregorian date to jalali, but in the UI we see Gregorian Calendar but in the input we see Persian date.

- This is the datePicker UI
  [image]
- This is selected date (Persian)
  [image]

Comment: check the module that you added if it convert the number according the language of the system. in odoo 9 there is JS file that convert the value to indian number (thouse are not arabic number ^^) `'1': '١'`

Comment: @CherifOdoo thanks for you comment, there is a few functions responsible for converting numbers and chars. example:  
     
`function _turn2englishNumber(value) {
        if (!value) {
            return;
        }
        var englishNumbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"],
            persianNumbers = ["۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "۰"]; `

Comment: if you don't need indian number just replace then by the same number and clear browser cache and i think this should do it

Comment: so you think the UI depend on the format.js? if so, what about the months and the days name? the problem we're have in the represent the days and the months correctly not in converting.

Comment: sorry i thought you wanted to remove indian number like we did, i'm assuming that you get the error invalid date?!!!

Comment: no, let's me explain better :). we installed Persian Calendar to let the users select a persian(Jalali) date in the form. but the users only can see the gregorian formats, and after the date are selected they see the output from Persian Calendar module.  so our problem is changing gregorian calendar UI to Jalali.